# Lost access to internal and external sd card because modified vold.fstab

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

I just bought a copy of Samsung Galaxy S4, rooted it using framaroot, installed busybox. Then i modified the vold.fstab because the internal sd card size only 1.8gb and i want my 16gb external card become the internal sd card, after i reboot my device some of my downloaded apps was lost and i can't open play store then i open file manager its empty. So i go to recovery mode and factory reset and nothing happening, i still cant access my sd cards. The two sd card are accessable in recovery mode so i moved  my external sd card to my another samsung device and downloaded cynanogen custom rom and gapps then i moved the external sd card back, i go to recovery mode and tried to install the custom rom but it failed. I have also tried using android commander in my windows pc but it didn't  work either because it says i have no root acces. Now i have no idea what to do, can someone please help me solve my problem if anyone can i appriciated it. Thank you....

Comment: What about restoring the original `vold.fstab` from the backup you've made before editing that system file? As that's stored in internal storage (so neither internal nor external SD), you should still have access to it.